# ¿Como fijar el encabezado de mi tabla?

Tags: html5, asp.net-mvc

Quisiera que el encabezado de mi tabla se quedara fijo, ya que cuando bajo el scroll igual se mueve el encabezado, estoy usando ASP.Net, HTML5, esto lo quiero hacer porque mi tabla trae demasiados registros y por eso se le puso el scroll pero al momento de bajar el encabezado igual desaparece espero y se entienda lo que quiero hacer, (NO ESTOY USANDO DATATABLE), eh visto ejemplos que lo hacen con  CSS o JavaScript, pero no se cual sea la mejor opción por buenas practicas. Saludos

esta es mi tabla

```
<div class="container" style="max-height:250px; min-height:10px; overflow:auto;">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tbRecetas">
        <thead style="background-color: #1359A1; color: #ffffff">
            <tr>
                <th class="hidden">
                    RecetaId
                </th>
                <th>
                    Asignar
                </th>
                <th>
                    Folio Receta
                </th>
                <th class="text-center">
                    Estatus
                </th>
                <th>
                    Código EAN
                </th>
                <th>
                    Descripción de Medicamento
                </th>
                <th>
                    Unidades
                </th>
                <th>
                    Preautorización
                </th>
                <th>
                    Tanto Receta
                </th>
                <th>
                    Cantidad Toma
                </th>
                <th>
                    Periodicidad
                </th>
                <th>
                    Duración
                </th>
                <th class="hidden">
                    Elegibilidad
                </th>
            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody id="tbodyRecetas">
            @if (ViewBag.Asignar.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in ViewBag.Asignar)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="hidden">@item.RecetaId</td>
                        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" id="checkTable" /></td>
                        <td>@item.FolioReceta</td>
                        <td>@item.Estatus</td>
                        <td>@item.CodigoEAN</td>
                        <td>@item.DescripcionMedicamento</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@item.Unidades</td>
                        <td>@item.Preautorizacion</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@item.TantoReceta</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@item.CantidadToma</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@item.Periodicidad</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@item.DuracionTratamiento</td>
                        @*<td>@item.Derechohabiente</td>*@
                        <td class="hidden">@item.Elegibilidad</td>
                        @*<td class="text-center">@item.Contador</td>*@
                    </tr>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <template>
                    <p class="alert alert-info">No se encontraron registros</p>
                </template>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta ofrecida?

Answer (score 0):

Este ejemplo basado en Bootstrap 3.4.1 podría ser de utilidad, vas a tener que darle unos ajustes con respecto a tu CSS.

```js
//@debounce(500)
window.scrolled = function(o)
{
  //altura visible + pixel desplazado = altura total
  if(o.offsetHeight + o.scrollTop == o.scrollHeight)
  {
 console.log("bottom hit");
    // datos de carga y actualización observables
  }
}
```

```css
.table-fixed thead {
  width: 97%;
}
.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 230px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed thead, 
.table-fixed tbody, 
.table-fixed tr, 
.table-fixed td, 
.table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody td, 
.table-fixed thead > tr > th {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h4>
            Fixed Header Scrolling Table 
          </h4>

            </div>
            <table class="table table-fixed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-2">#</th>
                        <th class="col-md-8">Name</th>
                        <th class="col-md-2">Points</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody onscroll="scrolled(this)">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-2">1</td>
                        <td class="col-md-8">Mike Adams</td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">23</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-2">2</td>
                        <td class="col-md-8">Holly Galivan</td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">44</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-2">3</td>
                        <td class="col-md-8">Mary Shea</td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">86</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-2">4</td>
                        <td class="col-md-8">Jim Adams</td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">23</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-2">5</td>
                        <td class="col-md-8">Henry Galivan</td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">44</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-2">6</td>
                        <td class="col-md-8">Bob Shea</td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">26</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-2">7</td>
                        <td class="col-md-8">Andy Parks</td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">56</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-2">8</td>
                        <td class="col-md-8">Bob Skelly</td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">96</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-2">9</td>
                        <td class="col-md-8">William Defoe</td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">13</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-2">10</td>
                        <td class="col-md-8">Will Tripp</td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">16</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-2">11</td>
                        <td class="col-md-8">Bill Champion</td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">44</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-2">12</td>
                        <td class="col-md-8">Lastly Jane</td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">6</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Código basado en: https://www.bootply.com/6s8NGoSS6M donde hacen uso de la versión 2.